# Block all outgoing connection attempts as per application via ipfw

Tags: macos, blocking, connection, ipfw

I need to **block all outgoing connection attempts** made by a particular app in order to prevent it from downloading updates automatically via **ipfw**?

Comment: any suggestions regarding the issue but Little Snitch?

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105896/block-application-access-to-network-via-a-cocoa-api-littlesnitch-apis). Doesn't sound like ipfw can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to [edit the hosts file](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/) and redirect the application's requests into the void that is 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a graphical front end to ipfw (it's still installed on 10.5 and 10.6, though not as prominently), I'd recommend [Flying Buttress](http://personalpages.tds.net/~brian_hill/flyingbuttress.html) (Shareware). If cost is an issue, Wikipedia has a [list of alternative user interfaces for ipfw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipfirewall#Alternative_user_interfaces_for_ipfw), many of which run on Mac OS X. Alternatively, you could go all old school and [configure ipfw by hand](http://www.ibiblio.org/macsupport/ipfw/).

Ipfw is, however, only an IP packet filter - you'll only be able to block access for all applications or none and only for a specific host and port. If you want to block all connection attempts by a particular application, you need an application-level firewall, the best-known of which is probably Little Snitch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to block a phone home or an automatic update because i've seen very few programs that don't let you disable automatic updates .

Comment: Google Chrome, Chrome OS, Safari... to name a few.

Comment: osx updates safari so you just have to turn off auto updating for osx.   This worked for me. for chrome " Go to 'Library' at the root level of your hard drive. In Library you will find a folder called 'Google'. In this folder there is another folder called 'Googlesoftwareupdate'. Delete it. Next time you open Chrome you will get a message saying that auto updates may not work and asking if you wish to enable them. Respond to this in the negative. No more auto updates."  this worked for me.  i have no clue about chrome os but i'm sure if you kill googles updater it'll kill it.